# How to send a List of JSONs to AWS Lambda function

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send a list of JSONs to be processed within a Lambda function.

I have tried several overrides on `handleRequest` but I have not been able to successfully get the Lambda to see it as such.

I tried...

```java
public String handleRequest(List<String> events, Context context)
```

And tried in the Test tab of the Lambda function to send string formatted JSONs (will be nested) like so...

```json
[
  jsonString1,
  jsonString2
]
```

But there is json exception failure that happens even before any of the Lambda code is executed. Not sure if there is some deserialization that is occurring leading to the issue.

Ultimately I want to do as specifically the documentation mentions I can do...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html

> `List<Integer>`, `List<String>`, `List<Object>`, etc.
> The event is a JSON array.
> The runtime deserializes it into an object of the specified type or interface.

Comment: Please share the error content on the Lambda side

Answer (score 0):

The `event` needs to be valid JSON.

If you wish to send multiple JSON records, you could provide a list within the outer JSON:

```json
{
  my_list: [
    {"name": "This is JSON 1"},
    {"name": "This is JSON 2"},
    {"name": "This is JSON 3"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I countered a similar issue when I worked with AWS Lambda/spring cloud function - we cannot send JSON data to Lambda because of deserialization issues so try to send your data as a hashmap or Pojo class for more information see, [AWS Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155595/aws-can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-lang-string-out-of-start-object)

Check my code in Github, which hopefully, help you to resolve the issue.

https://github.com/ARNR-CODE/master/blob/main/awspring/src/main/java/se/WeatherForCast/awspring/AccuWeatherHandler.java